# Array with images name to change my image every time i press the button in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, image, swift4

I have an array with image names `let arrowArray = ["up","down","right","left"]` and I placed an imageView and a button with an action in my storyboard

I want to change my image every time i press the button, 
Can any one help me ?

Comment: Please specify how you want to change the image. Do you want to iterate through the array and once it reaches the last element, start again from the first? Or once the last element is reached, stop changing the picture. Or just  choose a random element from the array each time the button is pushed. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view controller:

```
var arrowIndex: Int = 0

@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    yourImageView.image = UIImage(named: arrowArray[arrowIndex])
    arrowIndex += 1

    if arrayIndex == (arrowArray.count - 1) {
        arrayIndex = 0
    }    
}
```

This will display the up arrow first. You can change `arrowIndex`'s initial value to display different arrows first.

Comment: I got a crash ! Index out of range

Comment: @desperado_ah Sorry about that. Check my updated answer, and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **Xcoder** for the previous answer, i have fix the code so the image won't stop

```
func updateImage() {

    if arrowIndex >= 0 && arrowIndex < 4 {
        arrowImage.image = UIImage(named: arrowArray[arrowIndex])
        arrowIndex += 1
        if arrowIndex == 4 {
            arrowIndex = 0
        }
    }else{
        arrowIndex = 0
    }

}


@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

   updateImage() 

      }
```